# Piping to S3 not working when using a bash loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-s3

I cannot make s3 command to consume standard input from my bash script. Here is an example:

I have the following loop which generates random numbers every second and prints them to the console:

```
while true; do echo $RANDOM && sleep 1; done | cat
```

this works as expected:

```
$ while true; do echo $RANDOM && sleep 1; done | cat
21821
15692
...
```

but when I try to pipe it to S3 bucket like that:

```
while true; do echo $RANDOM && sleep 1; done | aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/loop.txt
```

I don't see the "loop.txt" file created in the bucket at all.
Piping of just one number works (same as piping an existing file):

```
echo $RANDOM | aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/one.txt
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: cause you have an infinte loop, so it never reaches the point when it's writing to the bucket. So make it finite and it should work.

Comment: But the point of s3 command is to consume the stream of data. I would suspect it's writing to s3 when the data arrives (every 1s). You can see that it actually produce the numbers "outside" the loop with this simpler "cat" example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An S3 object doesn't exist until the upload has completed. Per [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) docs:

> S3 never adds partial objects

Objects cannot be modified (which is what would have to happen if this object were to appear chunk by chunk). Until the upload completes, it's just a collection of streamed data chunks managed within the S3 service, not yet persisted as a user-visible S3 object.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Do you know perhaps what happen if the process that produces the chunks (the while loop in my example above) dies unexpected? Is there a way to make sure the streamed chunks always get transformed into a final file regardless of the exit code of the producer command?

Comment: If the client uses multipart upload (which is a special kind of upload for large objects) and doesn't finalize the upload explicitly, then it's orphaned and you are still being charged for the storage. You can query incomplete uploads and abort them. If your client aborts a regular upload, the chunks already in S3 will be deleted automatically afaik (because you have no other control of them).